# why does this css still keeps on functioning event if i deleted all the codes inside in it..?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

```
<link href="admin/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

the function of this line in my code is make my log-in form pop-up when a certain button is clicked.

i tried to delete some codes from it to makes some modifications but nothing happened and then i came to decide to try to delete all of its contents to try if the css is really working, then again, nothing has changed though the pop-up function is still there.

But when i try to delete that line in my code. everything is lost including the pop-up function.

Comment: Use browser developer tool, check the CSS file in the resources and it's content.

Comment: I suspect you're not uploading the changes to the correct place on the server.

Comment: @MaihanNijat i am using dreamweaver 8 and this codes are not yet uploaded to the intertnet.

Comment: @user3774818 It does not matter. Just open the page with browser by simply opening it.

Comment: @MaihanNijat well thats what i always do so i can view my entire output.. anyway.. what will i do next after i open it with my Google Chrome Browser?